# How to find touch area for android devices?

Tags: android, android-studio, touch, android-sensors

Im trying to find touch area for android screen like how much area is covered by any finger,i know about `event.getSize()` method but its always gives me `0` output and `pointerIndex` is also `0`. how can i find touch area for all android devices as further i also need to calculate touch pressure?

Comment: please refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016181/detecting-touch-area-on-android

Comment: FOllow this https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting touch area on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016181/detecting-touch-area-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
final View view= findViewById(R.id.view);
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "\"Touch coordinates : \" +\n" +
            "                String.valueOf(event.getX()) + \"x\" + String.valueOf(event.getY()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question regarding touch pressure. MotionEvent().getPressure(i) should return a value between 0 and 1 based on the "pressure" placed on the screen. In reality for capacitive screens it is the size of the capacitive object rather than literal pressure, but the concept is almost the same for fingers (fingers are squishy). Ranges higher than one may be returned depending on the calibration of the touchscreen.

If your screen is only returning 0 or 1, try testing on another device. Perhaps your screens driver simply does not return those values.Below link can be helpful for you

```
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure(int)

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/05/get-touch-pressure.html
```

Comment: i am following this [http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/05/get-touch-pressure.html] but `getPressure()` is always `1` in my case